# Java: How to make make overwriting to the same file I am reading from inside a GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, text, jbutton, overwrite

I am building a GUI which reads from a text file of all my customers' info and then display the info in my GUI. I wish to let the customer make changes to his or her information through my GUI and then by hitting the "SAVE CHANGES" button, I am able to save all those changes to the same text file I am reading from. I am new to FileReader/FileWriter and BufferedReader/PrinterWriter. Can someone please tell me how to design? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 7, is much easier. e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // You get this file with JFileChooser
    File selectedFile = new File("file.txt");

    // Read file and close file.
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(selectedFile.toPath(),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    // Modify some in the lines...

    // This replace the contents and close the file
    Files.write(selectedFile.toPath(), lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

}
```

Comment: So do I put this chunk inside of my SAVE CHANGES button Listener class definition?